# Как настроить подбор чисел в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, импорт, python-import

Код:

```
import random
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=random.randint(a, b)
g=random.randint(a, b)
print (c/g)
```

И может попасться любое число. Как сделать так, чтобы числа всегда попадались нацело делящиеся друг на друга (чтобы выводились сначала переменные c g, а потом ответ)? **Вариант // не подойдет.**

Comment: То есть вы желаете найти два случайных целых числа C и G в отрезке [A, B] такие, что C делится на G? Тогда мы можем сказать, что C = G * K, где K лежит в отрезке [A / G, B / G]. Сначала вам нужно зарандомить G, потом вычислить границы для K, далее зарандомить само K и потом присвоить C = G * K. (В вашем случае вам не нужно ничего присваивать - вы можете просто вывести K)

Comment: Если смысл на выходе получить просто целое число то можно округлить результат `print (int(c/g))` на выходе всегда будет целое число. Округление по правилам `print (math.ceil(c/g))` Такой вариант будет работать чуть быстрее поиска правильной пары (хотя в реалиях небольших скриптом это неважно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать цикл `while`.

```
import random
    
def my_fun(a, b):
    while True:
        c = random.randint(a, b)
        g = random.randint(a, b)
        if c % g == 0:
            return c / g

a = int(input())
b = int(input())

print(my_fun(a, b))
```

Comment: А возможно сначала вывести числа c и g, а потом вывести результат?

Comment: @CATpython да, возможно

Comment: return c, g, c / g